# Laravel 8: How to IGNORE a file which is imported to app.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

The `body` of my `app.blade.php` contains this:

```
<body>
    @include('layouts.navbar')

    <section class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </section>

    @include('layouts.footer')

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

And I `extends` this at all my blades, but I want the landing page of website to ignore `footer.blade.php` from `app.blade.php` which is this one:

`@include('layouts.footer')`

So how can I do that? Should I just manually include the footer directly at the blades or there is a way to ignore one of the included files of `app.blade.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Easily you can make 2 layout. Like one is app.blade.php another one is app_no_footer.blade.php. Ofc second one does not include layouts.footer
2. You can pass variable to layout when you extend

   @extends("app", [
   "footer" => false
   ])

Like this.

On your app.blade.php you check like:

```
@if(isset($footer) && $footer)
    @include("layouts.footer")
@endif
```

Comment: `@extends("app", [ "footer" => false ])` does not work, I also tried `@extends("layouts.app", [ "layouts.footer" => false ])` but didn't work!

Comment: You have to check passed variable in layouts file. I edited my answer, so check it